Fixing damage to my department due to nepotistic exec
I'm working with a team of software and devops engineers, and the team has recently been shuffled due to layoffs. Our technical lead, "Alice" (not her real name, of course), who works a lot of overtime and helps over 10 teams in our department, was recently screwed over by some exec, who basically credited the exec's cousin, "Jeb", with the success for Alice's work, and gave Jeb bonuses and stock commensurate with the quality of his "work". Jeb has never touched the projects Alice leads, so, this just looks awful to everyone, especially when some random unqualified, connected guy gets credit for a hard working woman's work. The work also literally saves our department $3M/year, so this hurts Alice's career too. Tech leads were ordered not to talk about this, and that just spread it through the whole department like wildfire, and impacted morale as well.
Alice has since dropped all of her "extra" work (inventing new solutions, helping multiple teams), and we're hurting. We're already short-staffed, and this just hits us harder. To remedy this, we hired nearly 2 dozen contractors, trained them, and tasked them with handling the work Alice used to do, but they are struggling to do a fraction of the work she used to handle. To make a point, Alice steps in for 1 hour, and does the work of the entire week's worth of the 20 junior contractors.
Is Alice just flexing, or is there something I'm not seeing here? Is a 10x engineer a real thing?
I'd like to mend the bridge here, but as Alice noted, our exec "burned the bridge and p*ssed on the ashes". Is there any way to patch up this situation?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"I'm working with a team of software and devops engineers" - Please clarify your position in relation to that team. What have you been old to do with them? Are you their new lead? Are you Alice's replacement? Do you have clear instructions from management?


Is there any way to patch up this situation?

Well, how to put this...
No.

Look, this isn't the kind of situation in which Jeb borrowed Alice's favourite toy and you can just give it back with a cherry on top.
Alice knows she has been screwed by Jeb, by the exec, and by everyone who allowed that to happen. Every other expert worker knows Alice was screwed by Jeb, by the exec, and by everyone who allowed that to happen. If your company does not manage to keep one of their top performers saving $3M/year safe from this, who is safe?
Make no mistake, your company is seriously broken. That this happened at all shows everyone your company is seriously broken. That the "remedy" was to hire 2 dozen contractors shows everyone your company is seriously broken. That your instinct is to suspect Alice is the one exploiting you shows everyone your company is seriously broken. That you have orders to cancel bonuses and hire exploited junior engineers shows everyone your company is seriously broken.
Your best bet is to learn from this how not to manage your golden goose. And then look for a new company that still has one.

Yes, I do not believe this is "patchable". Other suggestion like pay increases and apologies might at best work as a temporary fix. But the problem is deeply rooted at the top. There are no signs this is fixable long-term. Even if Alice accepts a pay increase + whatever else, chances are there will be more actions by the company that will make Alice reconsider. In fact, chances are, Alice will be looking for a job anyway, so any pay increase would be accepted (because: more money) but it will not fix even get Alice to stay.

@VLAZ agreed, but from the company's (and thus likely Von's) perspective, the pay increase might get Alice to stay a tiny bit longer - time which might be used for a knowledge transfer from Alice to... well, I doubt those freshly hired underpaid juniors would be a good target. My recommendation would be "whichever of the longer-term employees is least likely to jump ship right along with Alice". I'd say Jeb, but I doubt that would work out well - so look for those who the company has been treating well, is paying well, and have as little contact to Alice as possible. Good luck, you'll need it

To clarify: Alice's knowledge won't be completely transfered. But anything that WILL be transfered to another person or some form of documentation is better than nothing, and might help reduce (not negate) the serious blow to the company. Possibly to the point where it will not sink entirely and can recover. In time, and at great price, but at least "at all".

Sometimes an even bigger and bolder font is needed. This is one such time for the "NO".

Answering in reverse.

Is there any way to patch up this situation?

Its called money and recognition.. IE the money and recognition that Alice was screwed out of in favor of Jeb. Literally only way to fix this bridge. Also an apology from everyone in the command chain who didn't stop that stupid idea.  It might not be enough, but its the best that can be done.

Is Alice just flexing, or is there something I'm not seeing here?

Not really... There is a lot of difference in the productivity of 1 senior engineer who has been leading development on a project, and staying late for the past x years. And 20 junior engineers who have been working on a project for the past week, month, or year.
TBH it would take you at least 4-5 good senior engineers to replace Alice's productivity in the short term should she decide to leave, and by short term I mean sometime 3-6 months in the future... No way to immediately replace Alice's productivity. Long term one good engineer could probably get where Alice is in 4-5 years, if you are lucky. Though why one good engineer would stay with a company that mistreats engineers is beyond me.
TLDR: You might be in trouble, should she leave. And its unlikely that you company will be able to retain good engineers in the future. The story of how the company screwed over Alice is going to be water cooler talk/remain in the back of minds of your engineers for a long time.

Why does each and every team member supposedly need to know all 4 at the same time

Because it is an integrated system? If you divide that knowledge across 4 people instead of one, that means that you can no longer fix bugs in the system because the knowledge is too diffuse for them to make connections and see bugs that are occurring across boundaries. Also its not that hard to become proficient in all 4 just takes a couple of years of learning things.

Apparently we "need" to use shell, python, terraform, and node, instead of 1 language

You apparently don't understand your product. As an outsider looking in, I would guess:
Node for web interface. Terraform to configure the cloud architecture for scale. Python unsure. Could be business logic (though node could do that), could be database scripts, could be productivity scripts automating tedious/repetitive tasks, could be your backend, who knows? Alice, Alice knows.
Shell is just there to automate mind-numbing repetitive tasks command line tasks.
As an aside... I hate node.js a lot. javascript is a horribly designed language. A nightmare to debug/maintain compared to reasonably designed languages. Often the only person who can maintain it is the person who wrote it. On that note, Alice might be the only person at your company capable of maintaining your system. And she just started looking for a new job. I recommend that you start polishing your resume, your current employer's future prospects are a little grim.
One final thing:

to remedy this, we hired nearly 2 dozen contractors, trained them, and tasked them with handling the work Alice used to do

Why didn't you just increase Alice's pay by the amount that you would pay 1 dozen contractors? Seems like that is cheaper both short term and long term than hiring 2 dozen contractors who are going to spend the next 3-9 months figuring out what is going on.
TLDR: Screwing your principal engineer is a bad idea. Engineering is a knowledge based job. The technical lead for your product, system, whatever, has an intimate understanding of how the system works that would take someone else years to achieve, if they ever manage to achieve it. The more specialized/innovative your product is, the longer it would take for someone else to become competent with it.
As a side note you wouldn't happen to have Alice's phone number handy, would you? I know some people who are hiring

"I know some people who are hiring" <---  HA HA!!!  This made my morning.

I'm under orders to cancel bonuses, and am only allowed to hire new engineers from specific countries.

@Von Jump ship. Everyone else will very soon.

@Von. Recently left a job like that. People that didn't got shafted pretty bad. Gotta read the tea leaves when they hit upside the head.

@Von Sounds like management wants to do everything short of constructive dismissal to replace their expensive engineers with cheap ones.  You may want to consider whether middle management is next.

@vidarlo: I don't think Von needs to jump ship. I think he needs to stay where he is until he completes his education. The management of his company will hand him his diploma soon enough.

@vidarlo I heavily suspect Alice has started the jump

Hey, I'd be willing to pretend to be 2 dozen contractors for OP's company. I know terraform, node, python, shell scripting, and will produce slightly more work than the team of 2 dozen of them in a week. Considering that is probably around zero, I think you'd be on to a winner

@Von your options in fixing this seem to be very limited. As in, you can't do anything you would need to do. I would prepare for the upcoming major fallout. Polish your resume, start job huntig, and in the meantime write a final email to your supervisor(s) describing the situation in detail, and the only ways you see to resolve the issue. If they refuse those, they can't blame you for the upcoming shitstorm (though they probably will anyhow).

Node for web interface. ... Python unsure." - Where OP said "node", it is possible it's actually just JS for a web application front-end. Then it could be Python on the back-end, JS on the front-end, Shell for automation, and Terraform for cloud deployment. Which is fairly minimal as web applications go.

Honestly, Workplace SE probably needs a [screwing-engineers] tag. There's a staggering amount of questions here all following the same template of "we did something really horrible to one of our key irreplaceable employees, we're really surprised to see it backfire massively, how do we go back to the happy days we used to have?"

Nice answer, except the node and javascript hating part, not really relevant.

@Neyt I disagree, it's actually very relevant. The point OA makes is that node.js, in their experience, is so messy that Alice is probably the only one who could ever understand the code she created, and her replacement(s) will struggle terribly.

Quotes 3 and 4 are not in the question text. Apparently you're responding to comments that have since been moved to chat.

@Neinstein & Barmar, indeed, it seems to have been relevant, at least partially. But, I still think that Questor could have been impartial in the response, like "[For node, it seems that] Alice might be the only person at your company capable of maintaining your system."

This —> “ Why didn't you just increase Alice's pay by the amount that you would pay 1 dozen contractors?”

@Barmar yeah, responding to comments he made, Which seemed relevant to the quote as a whole.

@Neyt Thought it best to expose my bias. Too let people know to take my listed opinions on node.js/javascript with a grain of salt.

If I was Alice - here is what my minimum terms would be:

The same bonus as Jeb + 50% (for stress, late payment etc.)
A company wide meeting to acknowledge my work
An apology from both the Exec and Jeb for stealing my work (to be delivered in said company wide meeting)
A nice healthy Salary increase
A Guarantee that Jeb and the Exec will never interfere with my work again

So - unless you have the power to do all that the answer to your question:

I'd like to mend the bridge here, but as Alice noted, our exec "burned the bridge and p*ssed on the ashes". Is there any way to patch up this situation?

Is: You have more chance of walkin barefoot on the moon than you have of repairing the bridge that your management has burned with Alice.
Your best option is probably to find out where Alice is applying for a new job and ask if you can transfer with her. Then give a really spicy exit interview.

It is real simple as you pointed out. Trust is slowly earned and quickly lost. "Burned the bridge and p*ssed on the ashes" really says it all.

@DogBoy37. Yup pissed bridges can only be rebuilt with raw cash

This bridge is so much more than burned and p*ssed on. It has been nuked from orbit, just to be sure. There is nothing short of firing both Jeb and Exec + a ton of money I would accept if I were "Alice". Pretty sure she is at least interviewing already.

Honestly, this seems to come off too strong. If a public shaming meeting is a requirement for an employee to stay, I'd say that the company would very likely not go for it. Heck, if I was Alice and I was told there would be a public shaming meeting scheduled on my behalf, I'd immediately start polishing my CV. The optics here are not great - many in the company will remember Alice as "yeah, the one who started slinging mud at Jeb, right". It's a double-edged sword, it's not only cutting the shamee but also the shamer.

@Fildor - Oh she is definitely interviewing already. without a doubt.

@VLAZ - See - I understand what you are saying - but for me (and doubltess the other people who up-voted this) - things like Nepotism and denying people the fruits of their labour - that really rubs the wrong way - and they are the kinda thing that is easy to do in the shadows - and so public admission of wrongdoing would absolutely be a requirement to stay, so that they cant pull that kind of crap in the future.

@TheDemonLord I'm trying to say that this isn't really a solution. It's unlikely to be accepted by the company and even if by some miracle it is, it will also reflect poorly on Alice. It's just a power fantasy to believe the company would go "We are gathered here today to flog Jeb for getting credit for somebody else's work. By the way, it was Boss#42 who have Jeb the credit" and then everybody claps, Jeb and his cousin/Boss won't hold a grudge, and everybody rides into the sunset on the wings of friendship. That's not really the likely outcome.

@VLAZ - Oh, I agree - The company by doing this, witholding bonuses and other things OP has said has made it pretty clear they dont care. Hence my point that OP has more chance of walking barefoot on the moon. But yeah - if I was screwed over that badly - that is the only way I would be convinced to stay - a public apology and a shitload of money.

Tbh: I do not see any realistic chance of Alice staying (given she has any self-respect). The company won't shower her in money nor will they repremand Exec (nor Jeb) in any way shape or form - let's be realistic here. Just not happening.

@VLAZ True, but the point isn't the public shaming, it's the public acknowledgement. Not just of whose work it was, but of how they screwed up. A basic principle of restitution is to be open about that, because if you want to keep it a guilty little secret to save your reputation, you're not making restitution. The very, very least would be for both those characters to make that apology to Alice personally in private, and mean it.

@Graham "the point isn't the public shaming," I'm pretty sure Jeb and his cousin will disagree. Also, if I was just another employee in the company, and I get an invite for such a meeting, it's very likely it will look like public shaming to me. Or if not exactly "shaming", it'd look like some sort of corporate politics ploy by Alice. In other words, still not what you envision there.

@VLAZ Which comes back to whether the company directors value Alice more, or Jeb and his cousin. If they think Jeb and his cousin still matter, all this is a non-starter anyway. And if, as the OP says, the entire engineering team knows the truth, frankly I don't see how it'd look like anything other than acknowledging the truth. If anything, the fact they could acknowledge screwing up when the victim pushes back would be a good sign of integrity to other employees. Right now, not only is Alice planning on leaving, but also every other employee as soon as they can.

@VLAZ Surely that's the point though? This is not Alice figuring out how she can stay, this is management wondering what they could do to make her. I absolutely agree management would not agree to this, therefore the point is that "There is materially nothing OP can do to get her to stay under these circumstances"

While this would be ideal, it's not politically realistic. After my small company was acquired about 5 years ago, the original cofounder and tech lead was shit on and eventually quit. He got hired back during covid when we needed his expertise to make emergency changes, first as a consultant and later as a full-time CTO. But he still didn't get along with the new management (he didn't get any stock, while I did as a senior engineer), and once the world calmed down he retired for real. ...

... I imagine there had to be some private mea culpa to get him back, I don't think there was ever anything public to the rest of the company.

Everyone saying the first part of the answer isn't realistic is missing the point hard.  Of course it's not realistic.  That's why the second part of the answer is there, the first just tees it up.  The company burnt the bridge beyond all reasonable repair, and Alice is leaving if she's got any modicum of sense (and it certainly appears she does).

Your question is a little confusing. You described Alice outpacing 20 juniors, but you want to know if that's actually possible? Did she do it or not? A 10x engineer is obviously a real thing you have one working for you.I think it is unlikely that there's something you're missing. An incredibly capable engineer who is intimately familiar with multiple projects at your company was screwed over and now you're paying the price. Choosing to think that she intentionally made her work hard for someone else to take on, as opposed to valuing her skills, is probably only going to bite you in the ass.

Is there any way to patch up the situation?

If I were you I would be doing everything I could to patch up the situation, but honestly the answer is probably not and you have to come with terms with that. If I were Alice, I would need at least a formal apology and my compensation that Jeb was given. However I also would imagine that someone with her skills could get another job fairly easily, and why would she stay somewhere that clearly doesn't value her like they should? More to the point, why do you want to stay at a company that gives out bonuses and rewards to people like Jeb and screws over people like Alice?

@Von Not a very good one apparently. As it seems that you believe 9 women can have a baby in 1 month.

@Von who gives a hoot if there's "such a thing as a 10x engineer"??? You have seen firsthand how skilled Alice is. Do you think she spends all of her time concocting how to write the most complex code so no one else can fill in for her, and then goes and works overtime and helps 10 other teams and fixes new problems and...... are you starting to see how crazy it is to assume that she isn't as good as she seems to be?

@Von by the way, "a bunch of underpaid juniors from low-COLA region" wow, I'm glad I'm not any one of them that has to work for you if you value them so little. By the way, if you think one senior eng would have been more valuable than 24 contractors, why didn't you do that?

@InBedded16 My boss has ordered me to only hire from certain countries.

@InBedded16 They are underpaid. That's a fact. I feel for them. I'm angry that all hires have to be junior (longer to train) and are likely to be less motivated if they're being exploited.

@Von: Just a quick heads-up: those juniors won't stay with your company once they're trained and no longer junior - yours is not the sort of company which builds loyalty. And in those low-COLA regions, every pay bump is worth a lot. So plan on training another dozen next year.

The word "underpaid" implies the speaker values them more than the person paying their salary does.

@Von if you doubt whether a "10x engineer" exists - you're experienceing the proof right now. As you said, your company just had to hire two dozen contractors to make up for Alice merely not being extraordinary.

Also worth noting that in functional organizations, a senior 10x engineer is going to just 2x the programming work and spend the other 4/5ths of their time contributing to the growth of junior engineers in various ways, documentation, and a whole host of other things.  It sounds like this org has pushed all the work her way and kept her heads down so none of that extra stuff happened, and now is paying the price when no one else has learned what is needed to fill the gaps.

@MSalters from my observation most underpaid juniors end up leaving before they become a net contributor. Infact their inexperienced cobbling together of code usually leads to exponentially increasing development costs. So companies that go down that rabbit hole end up falling further and further behind because they keep on throwing gas on the fire.
